# Open Post on friends wall screen for Android Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have to implement one use case for the android Facebook that is open friends post on wall screen directly from my application and close my application immediately once control transfer to Facebook app or Browser.

If Facebook app is installed then there is two options

1.User has already login in the Facebook app : it will open post on wall screen for the friends Facebook account.
By using share intent we can open friends profile directly but i need way to open post on wall screen directly.

2.User is not login in Facebook app : it will show login screen first and after doing login it should open post on friends wall screen.
As calling application is already going to close when calling Facebook app then how to handle callback activity after login if there is any.

If Facebook App is not installed on Android phone then it should open directly post on friends wall in phone browser by given URL.(What would be the URL?)

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

go to Facebook SDK for Android Tutorial and learen there is a lot work you have to do
 
 
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious

i hope this helps